# Search Spell-Correction index is locked by another reindex process. Skipping

Tags: magento2

When installing sphinx advanced search i had no problems, everything works. Accept for the reindex part of the installation. It won't reindex because of another reindex process?

When i try: `php -f bin/magento indexer:reindex mst_misspell` multiple times i sometimes get another message:

`php -f bin/magento indexer:reindex` terminated by signal SIGSEGV (Address boundary error)'

What is this problem and how can i solve this?

Answer (score 2):

try to reset first with

```
php bin/magento indexer:reset mst_misspell
```

and then try

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex mst_misspell
```